# Magento 2.4.2: The following modules are outdated: Perfectmakeupmirrors_PmmHead schema: current version - none, required version - 0.0.1

Tags: magento2.3, module, event-observer, no-index

I just created a custom module to add a metatag in a category page of our Magento site by making use of event and observer. When reloading the category page, below is the error I see. I re-ran the upgrade command but the error persists.

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Please upgrade your database: Run "bin/magento setup:upgrade" from the Magento root directory.
The following modules are outdated:
Perfectmakeupmirrors_PmmHead schema: current version - none, required version - 0.0.1
Perfectmakeupmirrors_PmmHead data: current version - none, required version - 0.0.1

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Please upgrade your database: Run "bin/magento setup:upgrade" from the Magento root directory.
The following modules are outdated:
Perfectmakeupmirrors_PmmHead schema: current version - none, required version - 0.0.1
Perfectmakeupmirrors_PmmHead data: current version - none, required version - 0.0.1
<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php:71]
#2 Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#3 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/swissup/module-amp/Plugin/Framework/FrontController.php:48]
#4 Swissup\Amp\Plugin\Framework\FrontController->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#5 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#6 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:23]
#7 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:116]
#8 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php:23]
#9 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:263]
#10 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at [pub/index.php:29]
</pre>
```

Comment: check in your database with below query
SELECT * FROM `setup_module`  where module =  "Perfectmakeupmirrors_PmmHead"

Comment: delete it and execute setup:upgrade command.

Comment: You mean delete that record from the table?

Comment: yes, forbackup rename records and execute setup:upgrade command

Comment: S.P, thanks a lot. It got fixed. Final thing is the code you wrote to set noindex nofollow. I created a new post here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72258894/setting-noindex-nofollow-in-a-category-page-of-magento-site . $this->request->getActionName() is returning "View" when I open that category page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep your database backup before do it.

delete your module entry from `setup_module` table.
Ex.

```
SELECT * FROM setup_module where module = "Perfectmakeupmirrors_PmmHead";
delete  FROM setup_module where module = "Perfectmakeupmirrors_PmmHead";
```

and execute `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Comment: S.P, could you please answer my post on setting the noindex nofollow. The code in execute method doesn't seem to be doing the job. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72258894/setting-noindex-nofollow-in-a-category-page-of-magento-site

Comment: Hi Dhiren, could you please have a look at the related post here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/358323/magento-2-4-2-unable-to-process-binding-ifnot-functionreturn-customer-fu I'm struggling to fix this for over 10 days now. I added as much information about the problem as possible.